# How to fix my locale to display Unicode correctly in irssi?

Tags: linux, language, unicode, locale, irssi

I've just arrived in my new lab and japan and the server I can use has only Japanese locales. A call to `locale -a` returns

```
C
POSIX
ja_JP
ja_JP.eucjp
ja_JP.ujis
ja_JP.utf8
japanese
japanese.euc
```

So I changed my environment variables and now my locale is set to `ja_JP.utf8` which should support Unicode just fine. A call to locale now returns (changed from eucjp):

```
LANG=ja_JP.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

I can read file containing Japanese characters in Unicode just fine, whether I'm using less, emacs or vim and connecting from PuTTY or a remote xterm with cygwin. It also seem to display other Unicode characters fine.

But here comes the problem: if I type something in Japanese it seems to go wrong. I like to use IRC and for some reason, while I can read perfectly fine any Japanese character if I type something it's sent as garbage for other people. I'm using the configuration found here http://xkr47.outerspace.dyndns.org/howtos/irssi-utf-8-guide.txt

I'm getting these results for 
`/set charset`

```
term_charset = utf-8
recode_out_default_charset = ISO-8859-15
```

and `/set recode`

```
recode = ON
recode_autodetect_utf8 = ON
recode_fallback = ISO-8859-15
recode_out_default_charset = ISO-8859-15
recode_transliterate = ON
```

If you have suggestions, please try to think of a way which doesn't require root rights if possible since it would take forever for the administrator to actually do something on the server. I've looked up a lot online about locale but I didn't find anything about this problem.

Comment: Which IRC client are you using? If you run `cat > testfile.txt`, does it store the typed text correctly?

Comment: I'm running irssi. I'm using the same config file as on my other server where everything works fine. I can't try cat now but I will do this tomorrow when I get back in the lab.

Comment: With cat I'm getting a textfile I can read on both Linux and Windows. Notepad++ says it's encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. Native notepad also opens it fine. Documents I create with `nano` also use this encoding.

Comment: So your terminal is working fine, but Irssi is interpreting things weirdly. Could you check what `/exec locale` outputs, as well as `/set charset` and `/set recode`?

Comment: I'm getting `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` (and the other lines same, `LC_ALL` not set), `term_charset = utf-8` and `recode_out_default_charset = ISO-8859-15` and for the last one
`recode = ON
recode_autodetect_utf8 = ON
recode_fallback = ISO-8859-15
recode_out_default_charset = ISO-8859-15
recode_transliterate = ON`

Comment: By the way since I noticed I had `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` instead of `LANG=ja_JP.utf8` I quit that console again, logged out completely so now it's also `LANG=ja_JP.utf8` but it's still not working. I see my own message correctly but people don't receive it right while the messages other people send me work fine (I'm actually testing by sending messages from my other server, including characters not present in ShiftJS or eucJP)

Comment: It's most likely caused by `recode_out_default_charset` telling Irssi to convert everything to ISO-8859-15. Fix that setting.

Comment: What should I put there instead? I'm using the recommended settings from the irssi FAQ so I assume it should be working.

Comment: Uh, `UTF-8`, what else.

Comment: Thank you that does fix the irssi problem. I'm pretty sure I pasted the settings from the same place though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as determined in comments, Irssi was configured to convert messages to ISO-8859-15 when sending them, instead of UTF-8.

Change the output charset using:

```
/set recode_out_default_charset UTF-8
```

---

Also, if you're in mixed-charset channels, `/set recode_fallback Shift-JIS` might be useful (it changes the received-message decoding). Irssi will always try UTF-8 first, but if the decoding fails, it'll use the recode_fallback next.

Comment: Thank for for fixing irssi, but I still don't understand why the file names aren't working between Linux and Windows.

Comment: It's a separate program and should probably be in a separate question... It also depends on what protocol both Windows and Linux use to access that shared drive. (NFS? SMB/CIFS? AFS?)

Comment: I will edit my question accordingly to ask only about IRC and will make a new one for that then. Using Japanese Windows will make me spend some time finding out this information.

Comment: It also turns out that I didn't read the website (in the link) correctly since it did say that it would use `ISO-8859-15` by default for all windows. I just didn't think it came from here since it took me a while to fix everything to get any kind of display of Japanese characters in the console.